# Error on get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress

I'am using get_template_part to call another code from other file.
It's work fine when I use the code like this:
include get_template_part('category1', 'page');

I want to use another code, call from my option panel and then I change the code to be like this:

```
 <?php
 $post = $wp_query->post;
 if (in_category($up_options->cat1)) {
 include get_template_part($up_options->category1, 'page');
 } elseif (in_category($up_options->cat2)) {
 include get_template_part($up_options->category2, 'page');
 } else {
 include get_template_part('category1', 'page');
 } 
 ?>
```

Then I got an error:

```
 Warning: include() [function.include]: Filename cannot be empty in D:\0-SERVER\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Blogbold\category.php on line 40

 Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\0-SERVER\iwpserver\server\php\PEAR') in D:\0-SERVER\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Blogbold\category.php on line 40
```

The line 36 and 40 containt this code:

```
 Line 36 = include get_template_part($up_options->category1, 'page');
 Line 40 = include get_template_part('category1', 'page');
```

Really appreciate for any help.
Thanks.

Comment: get_template_part('category1', 'page') tries to include a file named "category1-page.php" from the same path. So it shouldn't fire an error like empty file name.

Comment: Make sure `$up_options->category1` returns a `slug` like `category1`, where did it come from ?